# How do I define object base authorization in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, authorization

I am creating an application for a video gallery, where I have different types of cds like audio, video, songs, movies etc. I need to give users access to only some of the cds types, for example only songs and movies.

How can i achieve this in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: asp.net MVC architecture

Comment: Which part exactly are you stuck with? What have you tried?  Do you have a working Login/Logout system and are wondering about roles and permissions for users etc.  Need more details.

Comment: example is :
i want to give a permission to user "A" to view CDs of type "Movie"

how can i achive this, i don't have any idea about authorization in MVC.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is going to get a very good answer.  The question is vague and in-specific.  Can users log in and out of your system already? Do you have a role based/group based/permission based schema setup?  Which *specific* parts are you having trouble with?  Please think about it, and break it down into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ViewCDsController : BaseController
{
    [Authorize(Users="A")]]
    public ActionResult MovieType
    {
        //select only the correct CDs to return to the view

        return View();
    }    
}
```

check this page for more information http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs